# How to place four radio button in a proper way (0,0) & (1,0) in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Here in my programme, I have used 4 radio buttons separately with two buttons in frame 2. but I want to show those r1&r2 at (0,0) position and R3&r4 at (1,0) position with buttons. If I use "grid" method it is not showing in a proper way.

```
import serial
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
class SerialViewer:
def __init__(self):
    self.win = Tk()
    self.ser = serial.Serial('com8',9600)

def bt1 (self):
    self.ser.write('on')

def bt2 (self):
    self.ser.write('off')

def bt3 (self):
    self.ser.write(self.v.get())

def bt5 (self):
    self.ser.write(self.v2.get())


def dialog(self):
    self.index = self.listbox.curselection()[0]
    #self.seltext = self.listbox.get(self.index)
    if self.index == '2':
        tkMessageBox.showinfo('CAUTION!','Run the PSP MODULE first!')
        print(self.listbox.get(self.listbox.curselection()))

    if self.index == '1':
        self.var1 = tkMessageBox.askyesno('Message', 'BYPASS relay on?')
        if self.var1 == 1:
            tkMessageBox.showinfo('CAUTION!','Turning on BYPASS relay')
        else:
            tkMessageBox.showwarning('FAULT!','No UPS found. please turn on 
    bypass relay.')
    if self.index == '0':
        self.var2 = tkMessageBox.askyesno('Message', 'You can only select 
    ADVANCE AUTO mode,Continue?')
        if self.var2 == 1:
            tkMessageBox.showinfo('Operation Mode','Turning on ADVANCE AUTO 
    Mode,')
        else:
            tkMessageBox.showwarning('FAULT!','No operation Mode selected')
    print(self.index)

def makewindow (self):
    frame1 = Frame(self.win)
    frame1.pack()
    b1 = Button(frame1, text = "ON", command = self.bt1)
    b2 = Button(frame1, text = "OFF", command = self.bt2)
    b1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    b2.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

    frame2 = Frame(self.win)
    frame2.pack(side = LEFT)
    self.v = StringVar()
    self.text = Label(frame2, text = '# main  power relay:')
    self.text.pack()
    r1 = Radiobutton(frame2,text = 'on', variable = self.v, value = 'on')
    r2 = Radiobutton(frame2,text = 'off', variable = self.v, value = 'off')
    r1.select()
    b3 = Button(frame2, text = 'send', command = self.bt3)
    b3.pack(side = RIGHT, padx = 5)
    r1.pack(side = LEFT)
    r2.pack(side = LEFT)

    self.v2 = StringVar()
    self.text2 = Label(frame2, text = '# main UPS connect:')
    self.text2.pack()
    r3 = Radiobutton(frame2,text = 'on', variable = self.v2, value = 'on')
    r4 = Radiobutton(frame2,text = 'off', variable = self.v2, value = 'off')
    r3.select()
    b5 = Button(frame2, text = 'send', command = self.bt5)
    b5.pack(side = RIGHT, padx = 5,pady = 30)
    r3.pack(side = LEFT,pady = 30)
    r4.pack(side = LEFT,pady = 30)


    frame3 = Frame(self.win)
    frame3.pack()
    self.d = StringVar()
    self.d.set('default')
    label = Label(frame3, textvariable = self.d, relief = RAISED)
    label.pack(side = RIGHT)

    frame4 = Frame(self.win)
    frame4.pack()
    self.listbox = Listbox(frame4)
    self.listbox.insert(1, 'mode not selected!')
    self.listbox.insert(2, 'no UPS found')
    self.listbox.insert(3, 'I/O port not ready!')
    b4 = Button(frame4, text = 'ACK' , command = self.dialog)
    b4.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 5)
    self.listbox.pack(side = LEFT)


def update(self):
    data = self.ser.readline(self.ser.inWaiting())
    if len(data) > 2:
        self.d.set(data)
    self.win.after(100,self.update)

def run(self):
    self.makewindow()
    self.update()
    self.win.mainloop()

SerialViewer().run()
```

Comment: Please make a [mcve] that we can run and test.

Comment: Please remove all of the irrelevant code. It looks like you've posted a lot of code that is completely unrelated to the question being asked (for example, if the problem is with the layout then we don't need any of the code related to the serial port)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be confused on how to use the `grid()` manager.

Looking at the results of your code I see things are staggered. I think you are changing both the `row` and the column` instead of just changing one or the other.

when you use the grid manager on a widget that grid placement is only in relation to what frame it is inside of. You can also use this same grid manager on the frames as well. This way you can decide on where the frames will go and not worry about in what order the frames have been created.

The below represents a frame using the grid layout when we have defined 3 columns and 3 rows from different widgets.

In each box you will see the where each widget will be placed when you assign a grid that widget. Keep in mind the below will only keep its shape if there is at least 1 widget in each row/column. If not the frame will automatically resize to fit its content.

So for example if we placed widgets at (0, 0), (1, 1), and (2, 2) then the frame will maintain its 3x3 layout. If we were to place widgets only in (0, 1), (0, 2), and say (1, 2) then the frame would now only have a 2x2 grid in it.

```
+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|                  |                  |                  |
|                  |                  |                  |
| (row=0, column=0)| (row=0, column=1)| (row=0, column=2)|
|                  |                  |                  |
|                  |                  |                  |
|                  |                  |                  |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|                  |                  |                  |
|                  |                  |                  |
| (row=1, column=0)| (row=1, column=1)| (row=1, column=2)|
|                  |                  |                  |
|                  |                  |                  |
|                  |                  |                  |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|                  |                  |                  |
|                  |                  |                  |
| (row=2, column=0)| (row=2, column=1)| (row=2, column=2)|
|                  |                  |                  |
|                  |                  |                  |
|                  |                  |                  |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Keep in mind that there are many tools to get more exact placements by using anchor, and sticky. The `grid()` manager is my favorite of the 3 different geometry managers in Tkinter but they all have their uses.

Here is a simplified version of your code to give a better example of how the `grid()` manager can format your widgets.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

class SerialViewer:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.win = parent
        self.makewindow()

    def makewindow (self):
        frame1 = Frame(self.win)
        frame1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        b1 = Button(frame1, text = "ON")
        b2 = Button(frame1, text = "OFF")
        b1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        b2.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

        frame2 = Frame(self.win)
        frame2.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.text = Label(frame2, text = '# main  power relay:')
        self.text.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        r1 = Radiobutton(frame2,text = 'on')
        r2 = Radiobutton(frame2,text = 'off')
        b3 = Button(frame2, text = 'send')
        b3.grid(row = 0, column = 3)
        r1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        r2.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

        self.v2 = StringVar()
        self.text2 = Label(frame2, text = '# main UPS connect:')
        self.text2.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        r3 = Radiobutton(frame2,text = 'on')
        r4 = Radiobutton(frame2,text = 'off')
        b5 = Button(frame2, text = 'send')
        b5.grid(row = 1, column = 3)
        r3.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        r4.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

        frame3 = Frame(self.win)
        frame3.grid(row = 1)
        self.d = StringVar()
        self.d.set('default')
        label = Label(frame3, textvariable = self.d, relief = RAISED)
        label.grid(row = 0)

        frame4 = Frame(self.win)
        frame4.grid(column = 1)
        self.listbox = Listbox(frame4)
        self.listbox.insert(1, 'mode not selected!')
        self.listbox.insert(2, 'no UPS found')
        self.listbox.insert(3, 'I/O port not ready!')
        b4 = Button(frame4, text = 'ACK')
        b4.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.listbox.grid(row = 1, column = 0)


root = Tk()    
app = SerialViewer(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to help :)